# Newsletter Checkbox on contact us page in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to add newsletter checkbox in contact us form in magento 2.1.6 same like customer create account  page.

i tried to use same block

```
 <div class="field choice newsletter">
            <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
            <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></span></label>
        </div>
```

but its give error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getIsSubscribed() on null in /home/schoolin/public_html/demo/app/design/frontend/Sm/furnicom/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml on line 72

How to fix this ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to create a new module with a new helper for it to check if customer is subscribed in this situation.

> app/code/Stackoverflow/Contact/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2017 Toan Nguyen. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Stackoverflow\Contact\Helper;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber;

/**
 * Contact base helper
 */
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber
     */
    protected $subscriber;

    /**
     * @param Context            $context
     * @param Session            $customerSession
     * @param Subscriber         $subscriber
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        Subscriber $subscriber
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->subscriber = $subscriber;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Check if customer subsribed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isSubscribed()
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * @var CustomerInterface $customer
         */
        $customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
        $checkSubscriber = $this->subscriber->loadByEmail($customer->getEmail());

        return $checkSubscriber->isSubscribed();
    }
}
```

> app/design/frontend/YOURVENDOR/YOURTHEME/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml

```
    <div class="field choice newsletter">
        <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($this->helper('Stackoverflow\Contact\Helper\Data')->isSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
        <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></span></label>
    </div>
```

> app/code/Stackoverflow/Contact/Plugin/Controller/Index/Post.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2017 Toan Nguyen. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Stackoverflow\Contact\Plugin\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post as Subject;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;

class Post
{
    /**
     * @var SubscriberFactory
     */
    protected $subscriberFactory;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Post constructor.
     *
     * @param SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
     * @param Session           $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }


    /**
     * Override execute() to subscribe customer before send email
     *
     * @param Subject  $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function aroundExecute(Subject $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        if ($subject->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $post = $subject->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            if ((boolean)$subject->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed') === true) {
                $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($post['email']);
            }
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

> app/code/Stackoverflow/Contact/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post">
    <plugin sortOrder="1" name="stackoverflowContactPost"
            type="Stackoverflow\Contact\Plugin\Controller\Index\Post"/>
</type>
```

Comment: I tried this, but after massage sent, email is is not added in newsletter subscriber and even customer not getting mail for subscribe

Comment: @sam I misunderstood your question, I thought you want to get the status is_subscribed in contact form. You will also need to change the contact form post controller to subscribe the customer manually.

Comment: what i have to add there, in controller file for subscribe?

Comment: @sam Please check my updated answer.

Comment: getting this error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Sfii\Bulkbuy\Plugin\Controller\Index\Post::getRequest() in /home/schoolin/public_html/demo/app/code/Sfii/Bulkbuy/Plugin/Controller/Index/Post.php on line 51

Comment: Do you have this `use Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post as Subject;` and your di.xml is correct? Also try to remove var/generation, can you dump values inside aroundExecute()?

Comment: yes, di.xml is correct and i also removed generation. used Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post as Subject  also and i just copied as all code you mention inside aroundExecute.

Comment: Could you try to move it out of if statement block and see how it goes?

Comment: yes, i tried ... but again same result, undefined getrequest() method

Comment: Oh my bad! Please update $post = $this->getRequest() to $post = $subject->getRequest()

Comment: Thanx Toan, now its working fine.