# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: product-images, sku, magento-2.1.7, media-images

Related to this- [Newsletter Checkbox on contact us page in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182810/newsletter-checkbox-on-contact-us-page-in-magento-2/190767#190767)

I am using magento 2.1.7 version. I created this module and it gives me error as:-

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Stackoverflow\Contact\Helper\Data::__construct() must be an instance
>   of Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in
>   G:\xampp2\htdocs\magento2\test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93 and defined in
>   G:\xampp2\htdocs\magento2\test\app\code\Stackoverflow\Contact\Helper\Data.php:34
>   Stack trace: #0
>   G:\xampp2\htdocs\magento2\test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(93):
>   Stackoverflow\Contact\Helper\Data->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))
>   1 G:\xampp2\htdocs\magento2\test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(88):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Stackoverflow\Co...',
>   Array) #2
>   G:\xampp2\htdocs\magento2\test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Fac in
>   G:\xampp2\htdocs\magento2\test\app\code\Stackoverflow\Contact\Helper\Data.php
>   on line 34.

How to fixed this?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Learn how to create a question you can refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 0):

It is showing that your helper is not using Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context class instance.

Please clear cache, generation folder too.

Update code like this.

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    )
{
      parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am working on developer mode. When i apply above change and by deleting var/generation, var/di folders it is working fine. But when i upgrade,compile and deploy it shows previous same error message. How to fix this to compatible with upgrade/compile process??

I used like:-
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        Subscriber $subscriber
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->subscriber = $subscriber;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

Comment: After deploy and compile , once again you need to clear cache folder, because after compile still your var/generation folder contain old data (static). please read the magento 2 offical documentation for more details.

Comment: I tried with this. Unfortunately it is not working. Enabled production mode and checked. But same error.

Answer (score 0):

If your `M2` mode is on `develop` mode then remove `var/generation` and `var/di` folder

OR ELSE

fire below command in your magento root directory

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```